# asp.net + facebook create event

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am trying to create an event in my app but keep getting this 'Invalid parameter' error:

```
(OAuthException - #100) (#100) Invalid parameter
```

when it hits:

```
JsonObject result = facebookClient.Post("/me/events", createEventParameters) as JsonObject;
```

Changed the parameters several times but still no help, anyone can advice:

```
   public string CreateEvent()
    {
            var accessToken = accessTok;
            FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
            Dictionary<string, object> createEventParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            createEventParameters.Add("owner", "Me");
            createEventParameters.Add("name", "Test Event");
            createEventParameters.Add("description", "This is a test event.");
            createEventParameters.Add("start_time", DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToUniversalTime().ToString());
            createEventParameters.Add("end_time", DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).AddHours(4).ToUniversalTime().ToString());
            createEventParameters.Add("location", "A Street");

            // Sample venue
            JsonObject venueParameters = new JsonObject();
            venueParameters.Add("street", "19 Phipps St");
            venueParameters.Add("city", "Toronto");
            venueParameters.Add("state", "ON");
            venueParameters.Add("zip", "L2A 2V2");
            venueParameters.Add("country", "Canada");
            venueParameters.Add("latitude", "43.6654507");
            venueParameters.Add("longitude", "-79.38569580000001");
            createEventParameters.Add("venue", venueParameters);

            createEventParameters.Add("privacy", "SECRET");
            createEventParameters.Add("updated_time", DateTime.Now.ToString());

            //Add the event logo image
            FacebookMediaObject logo = new FacebookMediaObject()
                                           {
                                               ContentType = "image/png",
                                               FileName = @"D:/Downloads/bb.png"
                                           };
            logo.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(logo.FileName));
            createEventParameters[@"D:/Downloads/bb.png"] = logo;

            JsonObject result = facebookClient.Post("/me/events", createEventParameters) as JsonObject;
            return result["id"].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok happens that I have an invalid date format. For FB docs:

NOTE - After the 'Events Timezone' migration, all event times are ISO-8601 formatted strings; they can no longer be specified as timestamps. The following formats are accepted:

Date-only (e.g., '2012-07-04'): events that have a date but no specific time yet.
Precise-time (e.g., '2012-07-04T19:00:00-0700'): events that start at a particular point in time, in a specific offset from UTC. This is the way new Facebook events keep track of time, and allows users to view events in different timezones.