# Facebook Event gives error "Param eid must be a valid event id"

Tags: c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am working on publish event on facebook by Facebook C# SDK. I am able to login and generate Access Token through it. But when I am publishing event I got error :

```
Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException - #100) (#100) Param eid must be a valid event id
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(String path, Object parameters)
   at FacebookSDK.Facebook.CreateEvent(FBEvent fbEvent)
```

My code is

```
public void CreateEvent(FBEvent fbEvent)
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient(this.AccessToken);

            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.eid = "524654568165461";
            parameters.owner = "me";
            parameters.description = fbEvent.Description;
            parameters.name = fbEvent.Title;
            parameters.start_time = fbEvent.StartTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            parameters.end_time = fbEvent.EndTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            parameters.privacy = fbEvent.PrivacyInfo;
            parameters.access_token = this.AccessToken;

            dynamic result = fb.Post("me/event", parameters);
        }
```

How i can resolve it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot I found the solution for it ....

You have to consider following link

[asp.net + facebook create event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247460/asp-net-facebook-create-event)

In my case i am trying to get data as dynamic but changed to JsonObject, it is working for me like,

JsonObject result = facebookClient.Post("/me/events", createEventParameters) as JsonObject;

I am using facebook sdk v 6.0.20

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a new event? If so, delete this line from your code:

```
        parameters.eid = "524654568165461";
```

If you are trying to edit an event, this eid is wrong.

Comment: my poor luck!!! I had deleted row. But still not working and error is same as above..